# Display data from 2 tables in ASP.NET MVC 5 on the same page

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5

I am in web development using ASP.NET MVC with C#. I want to create a dynamic web site. I have created a database DATABASE with 2 tables

- Product (id, name)
- Company (id, desc)

I create modelview to display data from both tables in the same page

```
public class HomeViewModel
{
    public IEnumerable<Product> product { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Company> company { get; set; }
}
```

How can I display the first product (`id==1`) and all company on the same page home?

NB : I use ASP.NET MVC and C# (not ASP.NET Core MVC)

Comment: What have you tried? What does your Razor view look like? This seems pretty straight forward. To get the first product, you can use something like `@Model.product.FirstOrDefault()` and get the properties for that product off that object. To list all companies, you can do something like `@foreach(var comp in Model.company) { … }`. I have a feeling you want something different from this, but if so it’s not clear based on the question.

Comment: Aside, your properties should be `Products` and `Companies` since a) they are collections (and should thus be plural), and b) public members (and should thus be `PascalCase`).

Comment: There are thousands of tutorials that cover this. Google is your friend.

Answer (score 0):

With view model like this:

```
public class Product
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Company
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Desc { get; set; }
}

public class HomeViewModel
{
    public IEnumerable<Product> Products { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Company> Companies { get; set; }
}
```

Simple razor markup for first product and all companies can be looks like this:

```
@model HomeViewModel

<h1>Products</h1>
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Id</th>
            <th>Name</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model.Products.Take(1))
        {
            <tr>
                <td>@item.Id</td>
                <td>@item.Name</td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>

<h1>Companies</h1>
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Id</th>
            <th>Desc</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model.Companies)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>@item.Id</td>
                <td>@item.Desc</td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```